# CloudFront for website with custom CMS hosted out of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've got a website with custom CMS hosted outside of AWS.

How can I set up CloudFront? 
My idea is to upload current content to S3 bucket. Set CloudFront up with origin from that S3.

This also require some changes in CMS itself:

- To replace static content (pics) urls for the one from S3bucket.
- Check if file exists on S3 then use S3 if not use copy on local server.
- To interact with S3 butcket API. (uploading/deleting)

  - When uploading new file, upload it to S3bucket too
  - When deleting file, delete it from S3 too
  - Delete only from the bucket.

Is there any other easier way? Mayby I'm just overthinking and cannot see the simplest solution.

Comment: CloudFront can do some of that for you, plucking off requests for certain path patterns, checking S3 first and then going to your server only if S3 doesn't have the file.  Do you have the ability to modify the code in the custom CMS?  Is the content public?

Comment: I'm about to set it up. But yes content will be public (read only) on S3. Also I can (probably have to) do some changes in CMS code. Just to confirm if I'm not missing anything and my idea is the correct one.